# Coherence: Simple custom AddressProvider not working

Tags: oracle-coherence

I was trying to use `address-provider` for `well-known-addresses` configuration. But it is not working.

Here's my config file:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>

<coherence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-operational-config"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-operational-config coherence-operational-config.xsd">
    <cluster-config>
        <unicast-listener>
            <well-known-addresses>
                <address-provider>
                    <class-name>xilu.scratch.coherence.MyAddressProvider</class-name>
                </address-provider>
                <!--
                <socket-address id="1">
                    <address>127.0.0.1</address>
                    <port>8888</port>
                </socket-address>
                -->
            </well-known-addresses>
            <address>127.0.0.1</address>
            <port>8888</port>
            <port-auto-adjust system-property="tangosol.coherence.localport.adjust">
                false
            </port-auto-adjust>
        </unicast-listener>
    </cluster-config>
</coherence>
```

And here's my address provider:

```java
package xilu.scratch.coherence;

import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

/**
 * Created by xxilu on 5/18/16.
 */
public class MyAddressProvider implements com.tangosol.net.AddressProvider {

  private String[] addressList = {
      "127.0.0.1",
  };

  private int index = 0;

  @Override
  public InetSocketAddress getNextAddress() {

    if(index >= 1) {
      return null;
    }

    String addressText = addressList[index];

    index++;

    InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(addressText, 8888);

    return addr;
  }

  @Override
  public void accept() {
  }

  @Override
  public void reject(Throwable throwable) {
  }
}
```

It looks very trivial, but the cluster cannot be formed. 
I get log like this:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dtangosol.coherence.log.level=9 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Didea.launcher.port=7537 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/xxilu/Projects/scratch/Coherence1/out/production/Coherence1:/Users/xxilu/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/coherence/lib/coherence.jar:/Users/xxilu/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core.jar:/Users/xxilu/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider.jar:/Users/xxilu/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind.jar:/Users/xxilu/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations.jar:/Users/xxilu/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jackson-module-jaxb-annotations.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 15.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain xilu.scratch.coherence.HelloWorld
2016-05-19 00:19:42.117/1.064 Oracle Coherence 12.2.1.0.0 <Info> (thread=pool-1-thread-1, member=n/a): Loaded operational configuration from "jar:file:/Users/xxilu/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/coherence/lib/coherence.jar!/tangosol-coherence.xml"
2016-05-19 00:19:42.198/1.136 Oracle Coherence 12.2.1.0.0 <Info> (thread=pool-1-thread-1, member=n/a): Loaded operational overrides from "jar:file:/Users/xxilu/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/coherence/lib/coherence.jar!/tangosol-coherence-override-dev.xml"
2016-05-19 00:19:42.258/1.196 Oracle Coherence 12.2.1.0.0 <Info> (thread=pool-1-thread-1, member=n/a): Loaded operational overrides from "file:/Users/xxilu/Projects/scratch/Coherence1/out/production/Coherence1/tangosol-coherence-override.xml"
2016-05-19 00:19:42.268/1.206 Oracle Coherence 12.2.1.0.0 <D5> (thread=pool-1-thread-1, member=n/a): Optional configuration override "cache-factory-config.xml" is not specified
2016-05-19 00:19:42.269/1.207 Oracle Coherence 12.2.1.0.0 <D5> (thread=pool-1-thread-1, member=n/a): Optional configuration override "cache-factory-builder-config.xml" is not specified
2016-05-19 00:19:42.269/1.208 Oracle Coherence 12.2.1.0.0 <D5> (thread=pool-1-thread-1, member=n/a): Optional configuration override "/custom-mbeans.xml" is not specified
2016-05-19 00:19:42.270/1.208 Oracle Coherence 12.2.1.0.0 <D6> (thread=pool-1-thread-1, member=n/a): Loaded edition data from "jar:file:/Users/xxilu/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/coherence/lib/coherence.jar!/coherence-grid.xml"

Oracle Coherence Version 12.2.1.0.0 Build 60603
 Grid Edition: Development mode
Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

2016-05-19 00:19:42.798/1.736 Oracle Coherence GE 12.2.1.0.0 <Info> (thread=pool-1-thread-1, member=n/a): Loaded FMW commons version: 12.2.1-0-0-SNAPSHOT b60603
2016-05-19 00:19:42.885/1.823 Oracle Coherence GE 12.2.1.0.0 <Info> (thread=pool-1-thread-1, member=n/a): Loaded cache configuration from "file:/Users/xxilu/Projects/scratch/Coherence1/out/production/Coherence1/coherence-cache-config.xml"
2016-05-19 00:19:43.539/2.477 Oracle Coherence GE 12.2.1.0.0 <Info> (thread=pool-1-thread-1, member=n/a): The cluster name has not been configured, a value of "xxilu's cluster" has been automatically generated
2016-05-19 00:19:43.567/2.506 Oracle Coherence GE 12.2.1.0.0 <Info> (thread=pool-1-thread-1, member=n/a): Created cache factory com.tangosol.net.ExtensibleConfigurableCacheFactory
2016-05-19 00:19:44.020/2.958 Oracle Coherence GE 12.2.1.0.0 <Warning> (thread=pool-1-thread-1, member=n/a): Local address "127.0.0.1" is a loopback address; this cluster node will not connect to nodes located on different machines
2016-05-19 00:19:44.069/3.008 Oracle Coherence GE 12.2.1.0.0 <D4> (thread=pool-1-thread-1, member=n/a): TCMP bound to /127.0.0.1:8888 using SystemDatagramSocketProvider
```

And it stops there.

If I change the address provider to the socket-address style (as commented out in the config), things will work.

Answer (score 0):

[I posted the question earlier for documentation purpose. I've spent 10 hours debugging this issue and I finally found the root cause].

After spending 10 hours, I found the root cause.

There's one very subtle detail about `AddressProvider` implementation. The document says `getNextAddress` should return a `null` to indicate all addresses are exhausted. But there's one important thing it didn't say: after returning the `null`, the next call to `getNextAddress` should look like the very first call to this object. In another word, if you view `getNextAddress` as an iterator, the iterator need to reset after returning the terminating `null`.

So changing `MyAddressProvider` from this:

```java
@Override
public InetSocketAddress getNextAddress() {
  if(index >= 1) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

To this:

```java
@Override
public InetSocketAddress getNextAddress() {
  if(index >= 1) {
    index = 0;
    return null;
  }
}
```

Things will work.

Hopefully this can help people hitting similar issue.